# How to open NOT SECURE URL to automate through python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am facing problem about not opening NOT Secure URL to automate through selenium. How to open NOT SECURE URL to automate through python Selenium?

I expecting output to automating open NOT SECURE Web application URL and auto login page and automate clicks or opening buttons or actions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ignore-ssl-errors` option:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
```

also `allow-insecure-localhost` may help:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
```

and then

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com/')
```